# Java: How to limit access of a method to a specific class?

Tags: java, class

Here's an example:

```
class A 
{
   List l = new List ();
   list.insert("x");
}

class List
{
   ...
   public void insert ()
   {
      /*insertion occurs*/
   }
   ...
}
```

Is it possible at all to keep the insert() method public, but limit access only to class A so that no other class can access it, only when called from A?

Comment: You can make `List` an inner class in `A`, so no other class would have access to it. Other way could be setting `List#insert(A a)`

Answer (score 7):

I would pass the object that is calling the method as an argument, i.e.

```
list.insert("x", this);
```

And then check if the passed Object is an Instance of Class A

```
 public void insert (String x, Object o)
   {
      if(o instanceof ClassA){
         /*insertion occurs*/
      }
   }
```

Comment: This is no limitation, everyone can pass an instance of Object (or whatever class) to the method...

Answer (score 6):

If the method is public, everyone can access it. The trick to access control like yours is to expose a set of public operations through an interface, add auxiliary operations to a private class implementing the interface, and make your users program to the interface, not to a class.

Here is an example:

```
public interface MyList {
    Object elementAt(int i);
}
public class A {
    private static class MyListImpl implements MyList {
        public Object elementAt(int i) {
            ...
        }
        public void insert(Object element) {
            ...
        }
    }
    private final MyListImpl list = new MyListImpl();
    public MyList getList() { return list; }
    public void insert(Object o) { list.insert(o); }
}
```

Usage scenario:

```
A a = new A();
a.insert(123);
a.insert("quick brown fox");
MyList lst = a.getList();
System.out.println(lst.elementAt(0));
System.out.println(lst.elementAt(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can pass calling object as an argument and put a check in insert() method before actual code.

```
  public void insert(Object obj){
    if(obj instanceof A){
      //your code block
    }
  }
```

Please note that this will allow all the classes that extends A as well to call insert. If you want to restrict only for class A, add additional check.

```
  public void insert(Object obj){
    if((obj instanceof A) && obj.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("A")){
      //your code block
    }
  }
```

we can also achieve second case with only condition "obj.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("A")" as well.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do using access modifiers is to make the method package private (remove the `public` keyword) and keep  only those two classes in the same package.

Answer (score 1):

If all the "inner classes" stuff in the previous answers confuses you, there is another way that may be more intuitive (assuming you've learned about the `extends` keyword and inheritance).  You can simply make the `insert()` method `protected` instead of `public` and make `class A` extend `List`.  For example:

```
public class List {
   ...
   protected void insert() {
      //insertion occurs
   }
   ...
}

public class A extends List {
   ...
}
```

As long as no other classes extend List, only objects of types `A` and `List` will ever be able to use the `insert()` method.

Comment: Or classes in the same package.

Answer (score 1):

```
package problems;

public class Problem1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.methodInB();
        C c = new C();
        c.methodNotInB();
    }
}

class A {
    public void onlyB() {
        StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread()
                .getStackTrace();
        if (!problems.B.class.getCanonicalName().equals(
                stackTraceElements[stackTraceElements.length - 2]
                        .getClassName())) {
            System.err.println("You are not authorized to call me!!");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("You are authorized to call me!!");
    }
}

class B {
    public void methodInB() {
        A a = new A();
        a.onlyB();
    }
}

class C {
    public void methodNotInB() {
        A a = new A();
        a.onlyB();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it as inner class in A or you can do another thing ...
Let insert takes one parameter with type of Object and in the beginning of it check if the parameter's type is A .... and when you call it send the calling object...
maby its not a good idea but it will do what you want

Answer (score 0):

Put it into the permitted class and make it private.