# Java: Limit access to methods of a composite class (Interface and Composition)

Tags: java, interface, composition

```
@Getter
public abstract class BaseProduct {
    Account account = new Account();
}

public class ProductOne extends BaseProduct {
    FieldOne fieldOne = new FieldOne();
}

public class ProductTwo extends BaseProduct {
    FieldTwo fieldTwo = new FieldTwo();
}

public class Account {
    public TypeOne methodOne() {
        return typeOne;
    }

    public TypeTwo methodTwo() {
        return typeTwo;
    }
}

public class MyClass {

    ProductOne productOne = new ProductOne();
    productOne.getAccount().methodOne();    //accessible
    productOne.getAccount().methodTwo();    //not accessible (error)

    ProductTwo productTwo = new ProductTwo();
    productTwo.getAccount().methodOne();    //not accessible (error)
    productTwo.getAccount().methodTwo();    //accessible
}
```

So, I have two classes (ProductOne and ProductTwo) which inherits from a Base Abstract class(BaseProduct).
The Base Abstract class in turns creates an object of another class (Account)

Now i want to restrict access to some methods of Account class for ProductOne objects and similarly restrict access for some other methods for ProductTwo objects.

I think I need to create Account class as an Interface/Abstract class and create different implementations for it. Is this understanding correct? Can you please show me how to do that exactly?

Comment: Maybe this is what you're searching for? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549394/java-how-to-limit-access-of-a-method-to-a-specific-class

Comment: You can use `isinstance` to check for the correct instance or make use of the visitor pattern. I do however think that it would be nicer if you made a solution that uses polymorphism and simply injects the correct Account complying dependency instead of using a base class for that. Just my 2 c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have two lines of `Product` concepts here. What you can do is make both `BaseProduct` and `Account` abstract and use generics.

```
public abstract class BaseProduct<A extends Account> {
    public abstract A getAccount();
}

class ProductOne extends BaseProduct<TypeOneAccount> {
    FieldOne fieldOne = new FieldOne();
}

class ProductTwo extends BaseProduct<TypeTwoAccount> {
    FieldTwo fieldTwo = new FieldTwo();
}
```

This will allow concrete "product" types to be bound to specific `Account` types.

Then, remove `methodOne` and `methodTwo` from `Account` and have them implemented in actual "type one" and "type two" classes:

```
public abstract class Account {
}

public class TypeOneAccount extends Account {
    public TypeOne methodOne() {
        return typeOne;
    }
}

public class TypeTwoAccount extends Account {
    public TypeTwo methodTwo() {
        return typeTwo;
    }
}
```

With this, both of the following will fail *at compile time*:

```
//fails because productOne.getAccount() returns a TypeOneAccount object,
//which doesn't have methodTwo()
productOne.getAccount().methodTwo()

//fails because productTwo.getAccount() returns a TypeTwoAccount object,
//which doesn't have methodOne()
productTwo.getAccount().methodOne()
```